# After conversion VB6 to VB.NET, how to request and respond WCF using VBJSON which is not supported in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, vb6

I have a VB6 project with WCF which is using VBJSON to request/respond WCF. I have converted this VB6 to VB.NET(VS 2005). After conversion, VBJSON is not supported to request/respond to WCF. So added PW.JSON.dll to send/respond and not working correctly for Scripting.Dictionary. Please give me any suggestion which JSON can use for conversion to VB.NET.

VBJSON is a VB6 adaptation of the VBA JSON project at http://code.google.com/p/vba-json/

Comment: Use [Newtonsoft.json](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) or the built-in json deserialization facilities.

Comment: Alex K, Thank you for your suggestion. Is Newtonsoft.json third party tool? Please give me some link for  built-in json deserialization facilities. Thanks.